# Updating objects in python lists behaves oddly

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a Node class, that have a field called 'neighbours' which is a list. I want to update this list if I find a vector that is closer than those currently in the neighbours.

In this code snippet I'm printing the word and its neighbours inside and outside the loop:

```
def create_knn(self, k):
    nodes = copy.deepcopy(self.nodes)
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        for y in nodes:
            if (nodes[i].word == y.word):
                continue
            self.nodes[i] = self.update_neighbours(nodes[i], y, k)

        #print temp
        print(self.nodes[i].word + "----------------------------------")
        for j in self.nodes[i].neighbours:
            print("neighbour: " + j.word)
        print("\n")

    #print temp
    for i in self.nodes:
        print("word: " + i.word)
        for j in i.neighbours:
            print("neighbour: " + j.word)
        print("\n")
```

But the neighbours are different from when I'm printing inside and outside the loop.

I get this output (for 10 vectors).

Inside the loop:

> go_VERB--------------
>   neighbour: get_VERB
>
> make_VERB------------
>   neighbour: get_VERB
>
> get_VERB-------------
>   neighbour: get_VERB
>
> one_NUM--------------
>   neighbour: know_VERB
>
> see_VERB-------------
>   neighbour: know_VERB
>
> time_NOUN------------
>   neighbour: year_NOUN
>
> take_VERB------------
>   neighbour: go_VERB
>
> know_VERB------------
>   neighbour: go_VERB
>
> year_NOUN------------
>   neighbour: time_NOUN

Outside the loop:

> word: say_VERB
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: go_VERB
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: make_VERB
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: get_VERB
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: one_NUM
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: see_VERB
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: time_NOUN
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: take_VERB
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: know_VERB
>   neighbour: time_NOUN
>
> word: year_NOUN
>   neighbour: time_NOUN

I have no idea what to do. I'm new to python, so is there some behavior of lists I do not know?

This is my code:

class Node:

```
word = ""
vector = []
neighbours = []

def __init__(self, word, vector):
    self.word = word
    self.vector = vector

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.word == other.word
```

class KNNGraph:

```
nodes = []

def create_knn(self, k):
    nodes = copy.deepcopy(self.nodes)
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        for y in nodes:
            if (nodes[i].word == y.word):
                continue
            self.nodes[i] = self.update_neighbours(nodes[i], y, k)

        #print temp
        print(self.nodes[i].word + "----------------------------------")
        for j in self.nodes[i].neighbours:
            print("neighbour: " + j.word)
        print("\n")

    #print temp
    for i in self.nodes:
        print("word: " + i.word)
        for j in i.neighbours:
            print("neighbour: " + j.word)
        print("\n")

def update_neighbours(self, x, y, k):
    prod = self.calculate_inner_product(x, y)
    min_prod = prod
    min_n = copy.deepcopy(x)

    for n in x.neighbours:
        if (n.word == y.word):
            return
        n_prod = self.calculate_inner_product(x, n)
        if (n_prod < min_prod):
            min_prod = n_prod
            min_n = n

    if (len(x.neighbours) < k):
        x.neighbours.append(y)
    elif ((len(x.neighbours) >= k) and (min_prod < prod)):
        x.neighbours.remove(min_n)
        x.neighbours.append(y)
    return x

def calculate_inner_product(self, x, y):
    return np.inner(x.vector, y.vector)
```

Comment: You have `neighbors` as a class attribute rather than an instance attribute.  It is therefore shared by all the instances of the `Node` class.  You should assign its initial value in `.__init__()` rather than the class body.